# Can't Resolve/Find launcher with Playwright

Tags: playwright

OS: Windows 10

Node: 16.15.1

npm: 8.12.2

After setting up a playwright environment on Windows 10, I consistently receive the following error when attempting to run playwright

> browserType.launch: spawn UNKNOWN

I cannot find any reference to this issue on the web so far

I have yet to successfully make it past this point with Playwright in my environment even after breaking it down and setting it back up and trying in different locations.

I have went back to older versions and the same issue pops up.

I have attempted to force playwright to use specific browser (chrome, firefox, etc), and receive the same error with any and all of them.

For an example, this is the only output I ever receive after attempting to run playwright.

(The following isn't the only command I have tried to use; it doesn't matter what I use)

```
>npx playwright test --headed --browser=firefox

Running 2 tests using 1 worker

  ✘  [firefox] › src\tests\example.spec.ts:3:54 › Navigate to Google (141ms)
  ✘  [firefox] › src\tests\example.spec.ts:7:4 › Search for Playwright (119ms)


  1) [firefox] › src\tests\example.spec.ts:3:54 › Navigate to Google ===============================

    browserType.launch: spawn UNKNOWN




  2) [firefox] › src\tests\example.spec.ts:7:4 › Search for Playwright =============================

    browserType.launch: spawn UNKNOWN





  2 failed
    [firefox] › src\tests\example.spec.ts:3:54 › Navigate to Google ================================
    [firefox] › src\tests\example.spec.ts:7:4 › Search for Playwright ==============================
```

My coworkers can run playwright without any issues. When I run their files/setup/environment/etc, I receive the previous issue. When I give them my environment, their playwright functions without issue.

I have followed a few guides online from scratch and the same issue happens.

I have looked for some sort of global setting, some env variable, anything, but having no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `npx playwright install`?

Comment: I did. Turned out to be the Acronis software preventing it from installing/running properly.

Comment: Glad it worked out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was discovered that the issue was Acronis.

Acronis labeled Playwright as malware and blocked it from launching.

To resolve the issue:

- Turn off/reduce Acronis
- Remove PLaywright files
- npx playwright install